# Product SKU based on manufacturer

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sku, automation

I would like to generate the **product SKU automatically** for every product created in admin panel.

I have found this extension which works to generate the SKU based on product name and it's category, but I would like to change it in such a way where the **firs 4 characters** of the SKU are it's **manufacturer** name.

Can anyone help?

--> https://github.com/vijays91/Magento-Auto-SKU-Generator.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you modify the code based on that module, place the following codes after line 18 `$new_sku = "";` in `app/code/local/Learn/Autosku/Model/Observer.php`:

```
$manufacturer_name = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
if ($manufacturer_name.length > 0)
    $new_sku .= substr($manufacturer_name, 0, 4);
```

P.S: Depends on your requirement, if you don't wont to keep category name, comment out line 19-25